# A question on trig series

Tags: real-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, harmonic-analysis, trigonometric-sums

Assume $\{a_k\}_{k\ge1}$ is a real sequence such that $u(x) = \sum_{k\ge 1}a_k\sin(kx)$ is a smooth function, and for every $x \in [-\pi, \pi]$
$$\left(\sum_{k\ge 1}\frac{a_k}{k}\sin(kx)\right)\left(\sum_{k\ge1}a_k\cdot k\cos(kx)\right) = \left(\sum_{k\ge1}a_k\sin(kx)\right)\left(\sum_{k\ge1}a_k\cos(kx)\right).$$
What can we say about $\{a_k\}$? Can we show that there exists at most one term of $a_k$ that is nonzero?
Note that if we set $w(x) = -\sum_{k\ge 1}\frac{a_k}{k}\sin(kx)$, we have the relation $u_xw = uw_x$ and $w_x = Hu$. Here $H$ denotes the standard Hilbert transform.

Comment: Your sums should be surrounded by parentheses, right?  (I initially read them as nested sums, which doesn't make much sense.)

Comment: Yes, this says that $fg'=gf'$ (defining $f,g$ as the two series with the sines), so $(f/g)'=0$ and thus also $a_k/k=ca_k$, so $a_k=0$ for $k>1$. (There are probably other ways of doing it too.)

Comment: Thanks for your comment, Christian. This is the first intuition to this question, but the problem is that $g$ may have strange zero sets even the function is smooth. The fraction $f/g$ is not always defined. So we cannot use this to prove the argument rigorously.

Comment: I think we need to be careful about whether $f/g$ is defined. For example, let $f = x\exp(-\frac{1}{x^2})$. Define the function $g$ as $g = f$when $x\ge 0$, $g = -f$ when $x < 0$. One can check that both $f$ and $g$ are smooth and $f'g = fg'$. But $f/g$ is not a constant in this situation. The problem is that $x = 0$ is a zero point of infinite order. Thus if $g$ has weird zero set, $f/g$ may have strange behaviour.

Comment: Do we need $f/g$ to be defined everywhere for Christian's argument to work? Won't an open interval be enough? (Aside: $a_k =0$ for $k\neq 1/c$).

Comment: I was aware of this issue, this was just supposed to be a sketch, sorry for not making that clearer. I assumed that since one can also apply the argument to $g/f$, there will be a way around this issue. Michael's idea sounds promising too, especially since $f,g$ will be real analytic for rapidly decaying $a_k$'s.

Comment: Yes, you are right, if both $f$ and $g$ are analytic, then everything should be ok. The question is what happens if we only assume smoothness of $f$ and $g$. I think I should modify the question to make it more clear.

Comment: This ($f,g$ smooth, but not more) seems an interesting question. I guess (assuming the statement is true) one would have to use that $f,g$ are not just any two functions, but $Hf=g'$, with $H$ denoting the Hilbert transform . I have no clear idea how to proceed though

Comment: This is a good observation! I don't know how the Hilbert transform helps this problem, but this is actually where this problem comes from.

Comment: If that is where the problem comes from, perhaps it would have been better to transparently give this context in the original post (rather than having $fg'=gf'$ and $Hf=g'$ observed later in the comments)?

By the way, if this problem is solved here in a non-trivial way and later used in a paper, it would be appropriate to cite this mathoverflow post.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, sharpend! Sure, if any comments or answers here are used in a paper, this post should be cited. I didn't include the original problem since I thought the problem formulated in this way is more interesting and easier to understand. I will edit the post to include this.

Comment: @JacobLu Are there updates on this problem? Is still open or you found the solution? As you know Claudio Rea tried to solve it but I do not know if his solution was correct. Claudio died a week ago and thinking to him this problem came again to mind again. Thanks for letting me know.

Comment: @GiorgioMetafune I am so sorry to hear the sad news. This is really shocking since I was talking to Claudio by email one month ago. Unfortunately, the question is still open now. The previous answer by Claudio has really good observations, but there were some issues with several technical details. I am still trying to solve it and I will certainly let you know if there are any updates on this problem.